# Best Method To Store An Outline

Tags: python, list, object

You know how documents have outlines. Well... I have two lists that I have to represent the outline. One has the words. The second has the relative position of the words, i.e. 0 means top level and the higher the number, the more nested it is.

```
outline_arr = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]

level_arr = [0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

^^ would look like this:

- A
- B

  - C
- D

  - E
  - F

    - G
    - H

      - I
      - J
  - K
- L

  - M

    - N
  - O
  - P

    - Q
    - R
- S
- T

  - U
  - V

    - W
    - X
- Y
- Z

How can I combine these into a single object to best represent an outline?

This is more of a logistics question than a direct code question but I guess my lack of syntax knowledge is also contributing.

Comment: What is the significance of an outline level jumping from 0 to 2 and from 2 to 5? How do you intend to use the resulting object? Just to print it? To show it on a web page? To use it from your code elsewhere? And in what fashion? It's hard to recommend a solution if it's not clear what the intended use is - otherwise one could simply recommend you `zip()` the two lists together and that would represent the same data in a single object.

Comment: the single object is a `dict` of `outline_arr `:`level_arr` pairs...

Answer (score 0):

This would do it in one line of code with list comprehension.

```py
# the two lists
outline_arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
level_arr = [0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0]


# using dictionary comprehension
# to convert lists to dictionary
res = {outline_arr[i]: level_arr[i] for i in range(len(outline_arr))}

# print the answer
print(res)
```

And here is the single object (a dict) answer:

```
{'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 0.0, 'E': 2.0, 'F': 2.0, 'G': 5.0, 'H': 5.0, 'I': 6.0, 'J': 6.0, 'K': 2.0, 'L': 0.0, 'M': 2.0, 'N': 5.0, 'O': 2.0, 'P': 2.0, 'Q': 5.0, 'R': 5.0, 'S': 0.0, 'T': 0.0, 'U': 2.0, 'V': 2.0, 'W': 5.0, 'X': 5.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.0}
```

Comment: Also, note that the list `outline_arr` in the original question should probably be a list of `strings` . The question has `outline_arr ` as variables. Whilst the answer would still satisfy the question, i though i'd point this out too.